# Drupal reserve checkbox module?

Tags: drupal, module, view, drupal-views, cck

I have a drupal site I'm working on here: selkirk.treethink.net

I have CCK and Views modules installed, so on the frontend you see the Request Work page created using CCK. On the backend admins and students can view all the work post through that form with the Views module.

I need to add a checkbox that the person submitting the work can't see but students can see in the page that lists the work through "Views". This checkbox will need to only be able to be checked once as it will reserve the job for that student. But the same student that checked it needs to be able to uncheck it...And only that student (or an admin)

In other words: Just a little box that sits on the "Views" page that a student can check and then no one else can uncheck it afterwards except the student that checked it or an admin.

Is there a module that can do this?

Thanks, Wade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought when reading your question was [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag). There is already a thread in the issue queue about exactly your question: http://drupal.org/node/624746. What it comes down to, is that flag can do most of the job, but you would have to write some code yourself (or possibly use the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)) to register which user flagged the node.

Another option would be to use the [Workflow module](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) and create an 'assigned' state. I have not done much with workflow myself so I can't really tell you which option is better.

Comment: I ended up going with the flag 2.x and integrating with views 2.x and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module lets you specify create, view, and edit permissions for CCK fields. I don't think it will do everything you want, but it's a start.